Как ограничить доступ на управление внутренними настройками конкретного расширение в Chrome
У меня такая проблема, я хочу ограничить доступ к внутренним настройкам конкретного расширения в Chrome, например: расширение которое ограничивает функциональность YouTube, убирает ленту рекомендуемых видео, подписки на каналы, или даже строку поиска, мне нужно чтобы после внесения этих настроек этого расширения я больше не мог их изменять! Чтобы просто не было доступа к этому или типа того. я отправил фото конкретного расширения, я хочу уточнить: именно настройки самого расширения а не те которые находятся в "Управление расширениями/само расширение/сведения

С ограничением доступа на удаление у меня вроде получилось сделать я попробовал через настройки политики в реестр Windows.

Это я не сам сделал, а ChatGPT сильно помог вот по такой инструкции:
Понимание ключа ExtensionInstallForcelist
Ключ ExtensionInstallForcelist в реестре позволяет назначить расширения, которые будут принудительно установлены и заблокированы от удаления в Chrome. После добавления расширений через этот ключ, они будут отображаться в Chrome как установленные принудительно, и не будет доступна опция для их удаления или отключения.
Настройка параметров в реестре
Открой редактор реестра:
Нажми Win + R, введи regedit, и нажми Enter.
Перейди к нужному разделу реестра:
Найди путь HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome.
Если папки Google или Chrome отсутствуют, щелкни правой кнопкой на Policies, выбери Создать > Раздел, и назови его Google. Затем, в разделе Google, создай новый подраздел и назови его Chrome.
Создай ключ ExtensionInstallForcelist:
Щелкни правой кнопкой мыши на Chrome, выбери Создать > Раздел, и назови его ExtensionInstallForcelist.
Добавь ID расширений:
Каждое установленное расширение имеет свой уникальный ID. Его можно узнать, зайдя в Chrome по адресу chrome://extensions/ и включив режим разработчика, где будет отображен ID каждого расширения.
Для каждого ID расширения, которое нужно заблокировать, создай новый строковый параметр (в реестре они называются String Value), в формате 1, 2, 3 и так далее.
Для каждого параметра введите значение в следующем формате:
ID_расширения;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx. Пример: если ID расширения aapocclcgogkmnckokdopfmhonfmgoek, то строковое значение будет выглядеть так: aapocclcgogkmnckokdopfmhonfmgoek;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"

Я сделал и сработало:  теперь я не могу удалять это расширение (но при сильном желании я могу удалить все то что сделал в реестре и тогда снова смогу удалять это расширение а мне этого не нужно) поэтому если есть возможность ограничить внесения изменения в те папки которые я изменял или еще что-нибудь сделать чтобы ограничить изменения было круто!

Резюмируя: Мне нужно ограничить доступ к именно изменениям
настроек самого расширения а также ограничить доступ к изменениям в
реестре которые я уже внес (именно на удаление расширений)

